# How to use flutter to write a Charles-like application to implement a web proxy

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy, charles-proxy

I wanted to use Flutter to write a desktop application that would implement the functionality of the Charles application. Can proxy mobile phone network requests, such as HTTP requests, displayed in the app

I tried the following code, but it didn't work and my phone couldn't connect to the Internet

```
ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port).then((ServerSocket server) {
 // It doesn't work !
 }
```